# Rails inconsistent model associations call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, model, associations

I have a rails model for a user as:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :character_factors
  has_and_belongs_to_many :stats_factors
end
```

And my character factors model is as:

```
class CharacterFactor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :players
end
```

And my stats factors model is:

```
class StatFactor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :players
end
```

Within my `Player` model I have the following methods:

```
def self.character_factors(id)
  @character_factors = CharacterFactor.joins(:players).where('players.id = ?', id)
end
```

and another method:

```
def self.stat_factors(id)
  @stat_factors = StatFactor.joins(:players).where('players.id = ?', id)
end
```

The join on `character factors` and `players` looks for the correct table:

`players_character_factors` and performs the query properly

whereas the join on `stat_factors` looks for the table:

`stat_factors_players` and thus errors out. I'm not sure why it looks for two differently formatted table names for the exact same association. Is there something I'm not doing correctly over here?

Comment: You're using `has_and_belongs_to_many :stats_factors` and the class is named `StatModel `.

Comment: @max sorry that was typo, I'll correct that in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for my question.

In Rails for `HABTM` associations the table names are generated automatically in the `lexical` order of the `model` names unless explicitly specified.

In my case since I didn't specify the name of the join table so the tables which rails was trying to look for were wrong. I fixed it by updating my models as such:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :character_factors, :join_table => :players_character_factors
  has_and_belongs_to_many :stats_factors, :join_table => :players_stats_factors
end
```

and similarly for character factors:

```
class CharacterFactor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :players, :join_table => :players_character_factors
end
```

and for stat factors:

```
class StatFactor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :players, :join_table => :players_stats_factors
end
```

Comment: Additionally the `Player.character_factors` example method you listed is just plain wrong. You can get the same result by doing `@player = Player.joins(: :character_factors).find(id); @player.character_factors`. Which usually makes a lot more sense. If you really need to have a scope like that it should be in the CharacterFactor model. `scope :by_player, -> { |id| joins(:player).where(player_id: id) }`